# Layering text over JLabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jlabel

[image]

This is how I want my app to look like.

Trouble is, if I drag the JLabel with the "Hello, I'm Myra" over another JLabel (whose icon is the speech bubble), rather than superimposing or layering, NetBeans shifts the JLabels to be adjacent.

How do I superimpose ie. place the text JLabel on top of another JLabel?

Do note, I'm using NetBeans. It doesn't allow me to edit much of the JFrame or JLabel code.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans won't let you add components to a `JLabel`, it doesn't see them as a valid `Container`.

This won't be easily achieved using component labels, as the icon placement is outside of your control.  A better solution might be to use a custom component, such as a `JPanel` and manually draw the speech bubble image yourself, then using a combination of `Border` and `LayoutManager` it would allow you to add other components to it

This is a very basic example...

[image: Speech Bubble]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SpeechBubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpeechBubble();
    }

    public SpeechBubble() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                SpeechBubblePane bubble = new SpeechBubblePane();
                JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello, I'm Myra");
                hello.setFont(hello.getFont().deriveFont(28f));
                hello.setForeground(Color.CYAN);

                JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>What would you like to know today?</html>");
                message.setFont(message.getFont().deriveFont(22f));
                message.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                bubble.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                bubble.add(hello);
                bubble.add(message);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                frame.add(bubble);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SpeechBubblePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public SpeechBubblePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/speechbubble.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(19, 19, 66, 19));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
            if (background != null) {
                size = new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
            }
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight()- background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If I was doing this, I would consider developing up a "9-path" which would allow you to break the image down into 9 parts and scale the outer sections based on what the content requires, for example...

Comment: OP just wants to place one label on top of another, i.e., add a z-order. This is very possible with LayeredPanes.

Comment: @mttdbrd That's one approach, but doesn't take into consideration what happens when the content above the speech bubble expands beyond it's bounds.  Equally, you could achieve this with `GridBagLayout` ;)

Comment: Whoa. I think my solution is simpler and cleaner, but you get a +1 for a ridiculously complete code sample written in like 5 minutes.

Comment: @mttdbrd You could also create the same effect using an `OverlayLayout` manager, which would be easier than a `JLayeredPane`...in my experience...but none of these take into account what happens if the top level content expands beyond the bounds of image ...

Comment: @mttdbrd That's how I'd approach the problem, but I'd be looking towards using a 9-patch image to take into variable size content...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to add a z-order. If so, you need a `LayeredPane`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html